# FLS on Salesprice field

Tags: profile, admin, fls

How to Remove the Access  to Sales Price field on Opportuity Products.
When i am trying to edit the FLS of Sales Price it is visible to all profiles and not able to change the FLS.

I want to remove access to this field for few profiles, how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

@Prince, You are not able to give field level security as per your choice because the field is required on the field level. when a field is required.

Hence the field level security option is not available for you.

The required field will be available for all the profiles.